Reached a stalemate - new player question
Looking for help with the rules here. Playing a 2 player game and have reached a stalemate / can’t work out the solution.
We are both in a position where we have one card left in hand, but only melds of max 4 cards.
Is it impossible here to end the game? Neither of us can add to current melds, as this would leave us with no cards after discarding but no canasta?
Also we aren’t able to pick up the discard pile because only one card in hand, despite knowing there are enough cards of a particular value in the discard pile to make new melds? Is this correct?
Appreciate the help in advance!

When playing Canasta with only 2 players, a common rule is that you draw 2 cards from the deck instead of one:

Canasta can be played by two players, with a few modifications to the rules. Each player is dealt 15 instead of 11 cards and at each turn draws two cards but discards only one. Finally, two canastas are required for going out.

https://www.britannica.com/topic/canasta/Going-out
This rule prevents this issue. If you aren’t playing with this rule, then you would just go until the deck is empty which ends the hand anyway. And you could skip over the pointless drawing and discarding to end the hand early since it doesn’t matter.
Note that if you aren’t playing the draw 2 rule, then if one player makes this mistake but the other doesn’t; the other player can draw and play every card in the deck (expect the ones already played) before going out; which would jump them over 1500 points to end the game.

Ahh that makes a lot of sense! I’m presuming with more experience you just make sure you don’t leave yourself in this position too.
Thanks for the reply, I appreciate it!
